# Changing which field (could be called something else I'm unsure) is getting affected in a function

Tags: c#, function, loops, object

So I have a function that writes info about an object into a csv file. Since there's quite a few I want to make another function that will repeat the code while only changing which aspect is changed. In my case, it's player info so I have stuff like:

```
playerarray[i].Name
playerarray[i].Class
```

And so on. I was wondering if I could change which field (not sure if that's what it's called) I write in the csv file.

My attempts look like this:

```
 public static void WritePlayerInfo(Player[] playerarray, StreamWriter writer)
        {
            WriteSpecificPlayerInfo(playerarray,writer,"Name");
            WriteSpecificPlayerInfo(playerarray, writer, "Class");
            // and so on...
        }
        public static void WriteSpecificPlayerInfo(Player[] playerarray, StreamWriter writer,string arg)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < playerarray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 1 == playerarray.Length)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(playerarray[i].arg);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.Write(playerarray[i].arg + ";");
                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried making the ".Name" into a string that I change in the aspects of the function but to no result

Comment: I don't think what you want to do exactly is possible.  What you could do is create a `Dictionary<string, object> in your `Player` class and put each of the fields that you could want to write in that dictionary with a corresponding string key.  Then you could do something like `writer.WriteLine(playerarray[i].Dict[arg]);` where Dict is the `Dictionary<string, object>` in your `Player` class.

Comment: I second the above comment. But also is there a reason you don't simply do `writer.WriteLine($"{playerarray[i].Name},{playerarray[i].Class},etc.;");` for each line?

Comment: Well I feel very dumb now, That is a better way of doing what I wanted to do. Thank you very much!